# Class Protocol: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols

I have protocol from framework

```
public protocol BaseMappable {
    /// This function is where all variable mappings should occur. It is executed by Mapper during the mapping (serialization and deserialization) process.
    mutating func mapping(map: Map)
}
```

and i have my protocol with extension (default implementation)

```
public protocol DtoResponseRequestActionable: class {
    func transferToResponceAction(_ dto: TransferToResponce)
}

extension DtoResponseRequestActionable where Self: BaseMappable {

    func transferToResponceAction(_ dto: TransferToResponce) {
        var map = Map(mappingType: .toJSON, JSON: [:])
        dto.transfering(map: map)
        let json = map.JSON
        map = Map(mappingType: .fromJSON, JSON: json)
        mapping(map: map) // <<< ERROR
    }

}
```

but i have error

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable

How I can fix it, for default imp. If I copy/paste code from extension to every class, it works good, but I need default imp. Any solutions?

Answer (score 4):

This might help

```
public protocol BaseMappable : class {
    /// This function is where all variable mappings should occur. It is executed by Mapper during the mapping (serialization and deserialization) process.
   func mapping(map: Map)
}
```

The other way would be to remove class from

```
public protocol DtoResponseRequestActionable {
    mutating func transferToResponceAction(_ dto: TransferToResponce)
}
```

and add mutating to

```
mutating func transferToResponceAction(_ dto: TransferToResponce) {
```

Comment: public protocol `BaseMappable` is **protocol from framework**, I can not change framework

Answer (score 1):

You're calling a mutating method from a non-mutating method. In order for `transferToResponceAction` to call `mapping`, it also must be marked `mutating`.

Comment: 'mutating' isn't valid on methods in classes or class-bound protocols

Comment: Swift can't handle mixing class-requirements this way. You will need to move the `class` requirement to `BaseMappable`. The fact that you've marked `where Self:BaseMappable` doesn't extend the "class-ness" sufficiently. You either must mark this function `mutating` or remove `mutating` from `mapping`. So you must either remove `class` or expand it. This isn't for deep, intentional reasons. Swift just can't do it.

Comment: For more on this error see https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/protocol-oriented-problems-and-the-immutable-self-error/

Comment: but I can not change `BaseMappable` it is framework. If I change `DtoResponseRequestActionable` to `**mutating** func  transferToResponceAction` I getting error again

Comment: Then you will likely need to remove the `class` requirement from `DtoResponseRequestActionable`. This probably cannot be solved the way you're doing it.