# Extend swift Array -- mutability issue

Tags: arrays, swift

I would like to create a Swift 4 extension on a Swift Array. The function should sort the array in-place.

The compiler complains seems to assume that arrays are immutable, as it complains on the function I created. I'd like to solve this, but do not know how. Please do note that the requirement is to sort the array in-place (with sort) and not creating a new array (like one would do with sorted).

```
struct MyStruct {
    var field: String
}

typealias MyStructList = [MyStruct]

// requirement: extend MyStructList with custom sort

extension Array where Element == MyStruct {
    func customSort() -> [MyStruct] {
        return sort { $0.field < $1.field } 
    }   
}
```

Compiler complains: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable

Comment: `mutating func customSort()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45427102

Comment: and don't return anything `mutating func customSort() { sort { $0.field < $1.field } }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to be calling `sorted(by:)`, which returns a new, sorted `Array` instance rather than `sort(by:)`, which does sorting in place and hence mutates the `Array`.

```
extension Array where Element == MyStruct {
    func customSort() -> [MyStruct] {
        return sorted(by: {$0.field < $1.field})
    }
}
```

If you actually want to sort the `Array` in place, you have to mark your `customSort` function as mutating and change the function signature to return `Void`, since there's no new `Array` created.

```
extension Array where Element == MyStruct {
    mutating func customSort() {
        sort(by: {$0.field < $1.field})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`sort` is a mutable function that sorts an `Array` in-place. `sorted(by:)` is the function you are looking for. Rename `sort` to `sorted`.

If you are looking to sort the `Array` in-place, then rewrite your function declaration to include the `mutating` qualifier.

So the following:

```
func custom_sort()
```

becomes:

```
mutating func custom_sort()
```

The mutating function `sort(by:)` does not return anything, therefore your `return` is erroneous. Remove `-> [MyStruct]` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and rightly pointing out the CamelCase (I edited the question).

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. You have to mark the function as `mutating`
2. If you want to **sort in place** there is no return value

   ```
   extension Array where Element == MyStruct {
       mutating func customSort() {
           sort { $0.field < $1.field }
       }
   }
   ```

And please name methods / functions *camelCased*.